# Make falling sand disappear when it lands

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I have a slime riding a falling sand block that is flying through the air. I need the falling sand block to disappear when it hits the ground so that only the slime remains. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 3):

If you place a torch beneath the falling sand, the sand block will "break" and become a sand block item that can be picked up or ignored until it despawns.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't know where the falling sand will land. Good idea though.

Comment: Ah, I see.  I tried.  I'll leave my answer for other people who don't know the sand-mining trick (it works on gravel, too, but the gravel doesn't roll its chance to give flint, it always gives gravel instead this way).

Comment: @gatherer818 That is more useful than you'd think... I love using gravel for paths, so when I get flint it annoys me haha

Comment: @ben I play mod packs that add machines a lot, they typically have a grinder for ores. One of the side effects is the grinder can usually turn gravel into flint anyway, so I prefer pure gravel myself for inventory management, when I want flint I'll make it ^_^

Answer (score 3):

Create a scoreboard objective named onGround

```
/scoreboard objectives add onGround dummy
```

Set all entity's onGround scores whose *OnGround* tag equals 1 to 1;
kill all FallingSand entity's with onGround score of 1

```
/scoreboard players set @e onGround 1 {OnGround:1b}
/kill @e[type=FallingSand,score_onGround_min=1]
```

Put the last two commands on a 20Hz clock

---

If the ground is only made op of a certain material, for example, **stone**

You can use an execute with detect and test for the block below the FallingSand

```
/execute @e[type=FallingSand] ~ ~ ~ detect ~ ~-1 ~ stone 0 kill @e[type=FallingStand,r=0]
```

the r=0 at the end is to make sure that the fallingsand only targets itself.

Comment: `onGround` is never being changed.

Comment: could be that the FallingSand becomes a block before it can be detected that it has hit the ground, in that case you should use the second method

Comment: I don't know what the ground will be like, though.

Answer (score 1):

I already have a slime riding my block, but if you just have a block, you can make an invisible mob ride it and this will still work.

**NOTE:** All commands here, unless specified, should be run on a 20hz clock.

The solution I found was to let the falling sand become a block, then use the slime to destroy the block. First you need to detect slimes that have only just touched the ground, so they don't destroy other blocks. A scoreboard can be used to track this. First, create the scoreboard objective manually:

```
/scoreboard objectives add onGroundTicks dummy
```

Then add to the score for slimes on the ground:

```
/scoreboard players add @e[type=Slime] onGroundTicks 1 {OnGround:1b}
```

Any slime that has only just touched the ground for the first time will have a score of 1. Slimes that have never touched the ground have a score of 0. Slimes that have touched the ground before have a score that is greater than 1.

Next, you need to remove the extra blocks around the slimes with a score of 1. I am using barriers, but whatever block you are using, you must replace `minecraft:barrier` with that block. Only the barrier blocks in this example are destroyed.

```
/execute @e[type=Slime,score_onGroundTicks=1] ~ ~ ~ /fill ~1 ~ ~1 ~-1 ~ ~-1 minecraft:air 0 replace minecraft:barrier 0
```

You may or may not want to kill the slimes after that:

```
/kill @e[type=Slime,score_onGroundTicks_min=2]
```

Answer (score -1):

If you had a fast redstone clock hooked up to a command block with the following command in it:
`/setblock <x> <y> <z> air`

Then when the sand falls down the /setblock will change the sand to air ans the slime block will still remain.